# Route network through server

Tags: networking, centos, router, forwarding

Sorry if this has been answered. I truly searched thoroughly before asking.

I've got two routers, and a server with two nic's I want my network to function as follows:

MODEM -> Router 1 (DHCP HERE) -> SERVER (eth0) -> SERVER (eth1, NO DHCP) -> ROUTER 2 (no DHCP)

Router 1 IP: 192.168.1.1 (duh)
Server IP: 192.168.1.2
Router 2 IP: 192.168.1.3

I want all the devices plugged into router 2 to receive their IP's from Router 1's DHCP.

I've enabled IP forwarding for my server. I just don't know what to do from here! (i'm a tad new to networking in the linux arena)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question might be easier to understand if you specified objectives for this network rather than just topology.

The immediate problem is the eth1/router 2 connection: it has the same subnet there as the network between eth0 and router 1 has.

Those are two separate networks and they need to be on different subnets. To see why, consider Server1 trying to send something to 192.168.1.123. Which interface does it go out on? Eth0 or eth1?

Comment: The objective is to extend the network on the same subnet of 192.168.1.* while not placing router 2 in front of any of the devices currently connected to router 1 (specifically the server)

For the sake of conversion, let's suppose that router 2 is fairly unreliable and could be offline at any given moment. I don't want any of the devices that are currently connected to router 1 (which doesn't have any available LAN ports left) to have the potential of losing connectivity due to router 2 being offline

Comment: also, when I ping another address on 192.168.1.* from the server it goes out of eth0